# How to upgrade NPM packages to the latest version in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, npm

After I upgraded to **Visual Studio 2017**, I'm not able to see the latest version of the **npm package** in the `package.json` file, and unable to upgrade. For every package, I see `Unavailable`.

This is what I see in the `package.json`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well that behaviour is strange. I'm using VS Code 2017 and it works like it should. Maybe uninstall and install VS again? Is your NPM working fine?

Comment: The NPM version that is running on my laptop is 3.10.10.

Comment: Well I'm using 5.0.3. Maybe update to te latest one?

Comment: I updated the Node version to the latest in the Visual Studio External Tools. I can see the latest version of all packages while I'm editing the ```package.json``` except the ones that start with ```@``` like ```@angular/core```.

Comment: Mh that's strange.. Did u solve your problem in meanwhile?

Comment: No. I had to go to NPM website, get the latest version from there and update the ```package.json```.